# Stuck on computing distance travelled from velocity and yaw rate.

Tags: calculus, physics, euclidean-geometry, mathematical-physics, kinematics

I am somewhat stymied on what appears to be a simple formula. Here is the problem statement:

Assume that a rigid body is traveling with constant velocity $v$, and is rotating with a constant yaw rate of $\dot{\theta}$. Find the distance travelled in one time step, $\Delta t$.

My professor then goes on to say that:

The instantaneous yaw-angle at a given time step is: $\theta = \dot{\theta} \Delta t$. The distance travelled in one time step is therefore given by:

$$
d = \frac{2 v \Delta t \ \text{sin}(\frac{\theta}{2})}{\theta}$$

I am completely unclear as to how this was possibly derived. In order to convince myself that this at least made sense, I set $\theta = 0$ and used l'opitals rule to derive $d$ in the case of no yaw or yaw-rate, and we get the trivial solution. However I am still unclear as to how this formula was derived in the first place. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, let the constant yaw-rate be $\omega$. As the body has a constant linear forward velocity of $v$, it must follow a perfectly circular path.

Let us consider the path of the body from $t=0$ to $t=\Delta t$. [image: Figure 1]

We see from the figure that:
$$\phi_{G} + R = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\theta + 2R = \pi$$
$$\Rightarrow \theta = 2\phi_{G}$$

From the sine rule in the triangle we get:
$$\frac{sin\theta}{r_{G}} = \frac{sinR}{r_{C}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{sin2\phi_{G}}{r_{G}} = \frac{sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \phi_{G})}{r_{C}}$$
$$\Rightarrow r_{G} = 2r_{C}sin \phi_{G}$$
$$\Rightarrow r_{G} = 2r_{C}sin \frac{\theta}{2}$$

Now, we know that:
$$\theta = \omega \Delta t$$
And, (from rotational mechanics)
$$v = r_{C} \omega$$
$$\Rightarrow r_{C} = \frac{v}{\omega} = \frac{v \Delta t}{\theta}$$
Therefore, from the previous equation we see that:
$$r_{G} = \frac{2 v \Delta t sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}{\theta}$$

Same as your equation for $d$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However some issues: 1) How are you saying that $v = r_c \omega$ That cannot be true: $v$ is in m/s, while the units on the right hand side would give you meters*radians/second. Can you please explain this? 2) Why do you say that $\theta = \omega * \Delta t$? If the body itself it exhibiting a yaw-rate, then isnt the yaw angle $\theta_G$, and not $\theta$? Many thanks. I think I almost get it.

Comment: Another point of confusion: You say that the body must follow a circular path, (shown as the length $L$), but then you end up solving for $r_G$... well, which one are we solving for? Why arent we solving for $L$, since we are traveling on a circular path? Thanks.

Comment: 1) $v=R \omega$ is dimensionally correct because although radians is a unit of measure, it is a dimensionless quantity. It is just used to keep in mind the role of angles in certain quantities. See: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108569/does-the-unit-of-inertia-include-radians

Comment: 2) You need to remember that $\theta$ is the angle subtended by the motion of the rigid body after a time interval of $\Delta t$. The yaw-rate or angular velocity is the angle subtended per unit time. Hence, after a time $\Delta t$, the angle becomes $\omega \Delta t$.

Comment: Well, firstly I agree with you that the question needs to clarify on which distance it actually requires: $L$ or $r_{G}$. In this case, it just made sense for me to solve for $r_{G}$ and it reduced to the required expression whereas it's easy to see that solving for $L$ would simply reduce to $v \Delta t$.

Comment: Hi TheMagicalMachine. In regards to (2), my question is more like, if the yaw-rate is based on the object ITSELF rotating while moving forward, then why are we using $\theta$, and not $\theta_G$ as yaw? Put another way - why is the yaw-angle $\theta$, and not $\theta_G$? Thanks.

Comment: In regards to (3), thats true, but if it's moving on a circular arc as you say, then doesn't that either negate the fact that we are moving on a circular arc, if the distance is covered as $r_G$? Just trying to understand. Thanks!